# SRFI reference implementations in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

I'm interested in broadening my understanding of Scheme and I came accross [SRFI 1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html). I saw mention of a reference implementation, but I can't find it anywhere.

Is there such an implementation, written in some variant of Scheme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SRFI 1's reference implementation is linked to in the "References & Links" section of the document: http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1-reference.scm

Each SRFI will have its own reference implementation, usually written by the author of the SRFI. Some will work across many Scheme implementations, but there are occasionally reference implementations that only work for one or two Scheme implementations, that you may have to port.